# Rendering to another html page

Tags: html, node.js, express, render

I am selecting info from the database and rendering it to an html page. My queries work but for some reason when it sends it to the html page it displays an array that says object inside each index.

```
app.get('/watchlist',function(req,res) {
    var obj={};
    username =  req.session.username;
    con.query('SELECT symbol FROM watch_list WHERE username =?', [username], function (err, result) {
        console.log(result);
        obj= result;
        res.render('watchlist.html', { symbol:obj });

    });

});
```

```html
 {% block content %}
 <h2>Create a Stock Watchlist </h2>
 <p>{{ symbol }}!</p>
 {% endblock %}
```

This is what the output looks like-[object Object],[object Object],[object Object].

The expected out put is all of the rows selected from the query.

Comment: What do you expect a query to return if not an array containing row objects?

Comment: The query returns all the symbols that correspond with the username

Comment: And each symbol is in a *row* of the database table.

Comment: yes its returning an array